# why doesn't signal re-render when add a new item? Preact signals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, signals, preact

I'm learning `signals` features and met some issues:

1. if set `value={newTodo.value}` then I cant type in input field, there would be only one character be typed in.
2. if set `value={newTodo}`, I can type in input field, but my todo list `todos` never update/re-render in UI when I click the button to add a new todo item even tho `console.log` shows the list is updated already.

But everything would works fine if i change back to react hooks. Can anyone help? Thanks!

I also created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/signal-todos-jlnsg4?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponent%2FSignaltodos.jsx%3A20%2C35&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00063b6fwlo5r2f8%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00023b6f5a28ee69%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00033b6fhavqpbky%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00053b6fad7vfu1m%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B59.9289038695492%252C40.0710961304508%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrsc8qqx00023b6f5a28ee69%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00023b6f5a28ee69%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsce1x000023b6g6vjvud8z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A35%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A20%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A35%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponent%252FSignaltodos.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrsce1x000023b6g6vjvud8z%2522%257D%252C%2522clrsc8qqx00053b6fad7vfu1m%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00043b6faf8h19ka%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00053b6fad7vfu1m%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00043b6faf8h19ka%2522%257D%252C%2522clrsc8qqx00033b6fhavqpbky%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrsc8qqx00033b6fhavqpbky%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) for this issue.

```
import { signal, effect } from "@preact/signals-react"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function SignalsTodolist() {
  const todos = signal(["eat", "sleep", "play video game"])
  const newTodo = signal("")

  const addNewTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    todos.value = [...todos.value, newTodo.value]
    console.log(todos.value)
    newTodo.value = "" // Use setNewTodo to update the state
  }

  // const resetToto = () => {
  //   newTodos(["eat", "sleep", "play video game"])
  // }

  return (
    <div>
      Create a todo list with signals。
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={newTodo}.   // highlight
        onChange={(e) => (newTodo.value = e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Type to add..."
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={addNewTodo}>
        add new todo
      </button>
      <br />
      {newTodo}, {todos} {/* To display the array */}
      <ul>
        {todos.value.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: im looking into this and created a sandbox - i see what you mean. At first thought it seems like the component is just not rerendering the correct way which is why when you change it to state or hooks it works right (because these cause re-renders on update) 

im messing with a few things and will keep you updated

Comment: Are you using the Babel plugin? Usage changed in v2, make sure to read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into two usage issues at once:

1. You cannot use `signal` or `computed` in components. Use `useSignal` or `useComputed`.

> When creating signals within a component, use the hook variant: useSignal(initialValue).

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/#signalinitialvalue

2. You've skipped over the [React integration instructions](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#react-integration). Usage changed in v2, you need to pick between using the Babel plugin or `useSignals()`.

Comment: I added `useSignals()` it works for me now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`signal(...)` creates new instance on each render. When you update it, rerender happens and then signal gives you the initial instance. You should not use it inside component. Move it outside or use `useSignal`

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/#local-state-with-signals

Comment: i changed to useSignal but these issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

After some research....maybe attempt to use `batch` to make sure items are updated/rerendered.

preact is very fragile in the sense that the smallest thing can mess it up - ive been messing with a few different sandboxes and this seems to be the best working example but has a lot of overhead for a simple todo list https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/preact-signals-react-5qcp8r

TodoList.js

```js
import { signal, computed, batch } from "@preact/signals-react";
import { useAppState } from "./AppStateContext";

const newItem = signal("");

export default function TodoList() {
  const { todos, addTodo, removeTodo } = useAppState();
  const completedCount = computed(() => {
    return todos.value.filter((todo) => todo.completed).length;
  });

  const onInput = (event) => (newItem.value = event.target.value);

  const onAddClick = () => {
    batch(() => {
      addTodo(newItem);
      newItem.value = "";
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={newItem.value} onInput={onInput} />
      <button style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} onClick={onAddClick}>
        Add
      </button>
      <ul style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        {todos.value.map((todo, index) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={todo.completed}
                onInput={() => {
                  todo.completed = !todo.completed;
                  todos.value = [...todos.value];
                }}
              />
              {todo.completed ? <s>{todo.text}</s> : todo.text}{" "}
              <button
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px", color: "red" }}
                onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}
              >
                x
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <p>Completed count: {completedCount.value}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

AppContext.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";
const AppState = React.createContext();

function AppStateProvider(props) {
  const todos = signal([
    { text: "eat", completed: true },
    { text: "sleep", completed: false },
    { text: "rave", completed: false },
    { text: "repeat", completed: false }

  ]);
  function addTodo(newItem) {
    todos.value = [...todos.value, { text: newItem.value, completed: false }];
  }

  function removeTodo(index) {
    todos.value.splice(index, 1);
    todos.value = [...todos.value];
  }

  return (
    <AppState.Provider value={{ todos, addTodo, removeTodo }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppState.Provider>
  );
}

function useAppState() {
  const appState = useContext(AppState);
  if (!appState) {
    throw new Error("useAppState must be used within a AppStateProvider");
  }
  return appState;
}

export { AppStateProvider, useAppState };
```

from what ive heard from coworkers that have been at companies which use preact, unless you use it perfectly everytime, signals etc can become a nightmare. Also your code issue could be because of how preact is interacting with your framework because as the preact docs state, when you update value it should cause a re-render but it obviously is not

even in the example given, the state is not working fully as expected...try deleting unchecked items then checking a new item or add item after trying to delete unchecked..youll see some obvious render issues..

Comment: Looks like you need to do more reasearch bud. Preact is not older than React. Google it or look at their vs history 
Preact is a lightweight and faster alternative to React, designed to have a smaller footprint and better performance in certain scenarios. It was developed by Jason Miller and first released in 2014.

React, on the other hand, was created by Facebook and initially released in 2013. React has been widely adopted in the industry and is one of the most popular JavaScript libraries for building user interfaces.

Comment: Look at my profile :). Preact was developed first, under a different name, but very similar hyperscript-based API.

Comment: Preact is considered "new" in the sense that it was released after React and gained attention in the web development community as a lightweight alternative. When Preact was introduced in 2014, React had already been established as a popular and widely used library for building user interfaces. Preact emerged as a reaction to React's larger file size and the desire for a more lightweight library however you would have to use preact when react had breaking updates such as back when 16 was released which took them a while to update and support - this is why it is considered new each react update

Comment: Please stop regurgitating GPT responses. Saying it's new is simply wrong.

Comment: its a fact that preact has been slow to support new react versions thats the entire reason my work decided against it - ill agree that it is not new in the sense of when it was originally created but in regards to using it with react 18, it is a new version which has known issues with react - again this is what i know form coworkers, documentation and my own work experience with preact - thanks for your opinion which is all i gave as well which is why i said 'maybe'  - all ive done is try to help solve - not here for arguing opinions - take it, suggest an edit or leave it. thanks bud

Comment: Full compat has never been a project goal -- this is entirely irrelevant to the issue at hand anyways, as signals, while from the Preact team, have no inherent tie to Preact the framework.